# How to perform multiple commands on a list of files in bash (xargs?)

Tags: bash, xargs, command-substitution, process-substitution

I have a file that contains a list of files, and I want to perform two commands on each file.

Contents of files.txt:

```
file1
file2
file3
```

The commands I want to perform on each file are (for example) `ls -s` and `du`.

I want the output to end up being like this:

```
<ls size> <du size> file1
<ls size> <du size> file2
<ls size> <du size> file3
```

I know how to do this using a bash script, but is there a way to easily do this on one line, using process substitution or something?

I thought I could do something like this, but it didn't work:

```
cat files.txt | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 -I{} cat <(du {} ) <(ls -s {})
```

That came up with these errors:

```
du: cannot access `{}': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access {}: No such file or directory
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run a `sh` with `xargs`, in which you can put multiple commands, for example:

```
xargs -0 -I{} sh -c 'du {}; ls -s {}'
```

Comment: Thanks! OK, my follow-up question is, I want to get `du` to only prefix the line with it's measured size. The usual way is to do `du <filename> | cut -f1 | tr --delete '\n'`, but I can't use the single quotes because the `sh` command is quoted using single quotes. Is there any way to substitute all that for the `du` part?

Comment: You can quote with double-quotes.

Comment: Is there a way to escape it so the filenames can contain either single or double quotes?

Comment: @localhost Yes, using a wrapper script, instead of `sh -c '...'`. For example `xargs -0 -I{} wrapper.sh {}`. In this form the shell will correctly escape the filename in `{}`, and `wrapper.sh` can work with `"$1"`, as in `du "$1"; ls -s "$1"`